# Perl interpreter: convert '\n' into newline?

Tags: perl

I have a program in perl that is passed a string from the console.  If I pass the string \r\n from the console, it does as it is supposed to and literally stores \r\n into the console arguments as it was created like so:

```
my $str = '\r\n';
```

How can I make $str into a CRLF? For example; how can I make

```
my $str = '\r\n';
```

into

```
my $str = "\r\n"; #<--- perl converts \r\n into a carriage return & line feed.
```

How can I force perl to convert the string passed from the console into CRLF?

If I am not being clear enough, let me show an example:

```
my ($arg1, $arg2) = @ARGV;
print $arg1 . $arg2;
```

Assuming `$arg1` was passed `'Hello\r\n'` and `$arg2` was passed `'World!'` it will print `Hello\r\nWorld!` when I want it to print `Hello(newline)World!`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `unbackslash` function from [String::Escape](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Escape) to do this:

```
use String::Escape qw( unbackslash );

my $str = 'Hello\r\nWorld\r\n';

print unbackslash($str);
```